# How do I get all the users in an organic group with specific role programatically?

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups

I'm trying to use rules to send an email to all users with a specific role in an organic group when someone requests to join the group.

This code almost works. It returns all users from a specific group ($GID) with the specified role ($RID), but it doesn't restrict the role to that group. In other words, if they have the appropriate role in another group, they're included in the results.

```
$current_members = db_select('og_membership', 'om');
$current_members->join('og_users_roles', 'ogur', 'om.etid = ogur.uid');
$current_members->condition('om.gid', $GID);
$current_members->condition('om.entity_type', 'user');
$current_members->condition('ogur.rid', $RID); 

$result = $current_members->execute();
while ($res = $result->fetchAssoc()) { $members[] = $res['etid']; }

// Remove duplicate items.
$members = array_keys(array_flip($members));
```

What do I need to change to restrict the results so that it only returns users with the specified role ID within the specified group?

Comment: Why are you doing SQL on drupal??? That's what [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) are for. With views, you can do all that easily.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using db_select in drupal. I is a part of the Drupal api. I wouldn't advocate on using the php PDO driver directly, but in this case sTony is doing nothing wrong by using php --so long as it isn't in a php field :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple sql query, no joins needed:

ie. select uid from og_users_roles where rid=3 and gid=835;

```
  $members = array();
  $current_members = db_select('og_users_roles', 'ogur');
  $current_members->fields('ogur', array('uid'));
  $current_members->condition('ogur.rid', $rid);
  $current_members->condition('ogur.gid', $gid);

  $result = $current_members->execute();
  while ($res = $result->fetchAssoc()) { $members[] = $res['uid'];}

  // Remove duplicate items.
  $members = array_keys(array_flip($members));
```

Comment: Why did you use ```array_keys(array_flip($members));``` ? Why not use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)